# How do you interpret this output

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

Here is an output from a random intercepts logistic regression model.

[image]

I want to use this model to predict observations in a test set. However, it is not working in R. How would you write this as a formula in Excel?

Comment: The thing I do to help me understand this is to be sure to write out my model *before* running it. You should know what variable all of those coefficients correspond to. Also, only a couple are statistically significant, so you wouldn't want all of them in the your prediction anyway. It should be relatively simple to set up in R. [Here's a good link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999710/creating-a-new-column-to-a-data-frame-using-a-formula-from-another-variable) with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Why Excel? It is much easier to compute this in R. See `?predict`, in particular you will need to set the `newdata` argument of the function to the test dataset.

It is not difficult to compute predictions manually either. Since it is a logistic regression, if $\beta_0$ is the intercept, $\beta_a,\dots,\beta_f$ the coefficients of the corresponding predictor variables $a,\dots,f$ and $u_n$ the random intercept of the group $n$, the model predictions can be computed as 
$$p(x_i|n)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\beta_aa_i+\dots+\beta_ff_i+u_n)}}$$
If you are making predictions on different groups that those you used to fit the random intercepts, you can just remove the random effect term.